# How can I get the value of a variable in my nodejs file

Tags: node.js, local-storage

I have a variable and it has it's value from LocalStoage. How can I get this value to my app.js nodejs file. I want to create a api with this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js runs on the backend, Local storage is inside the browser(frontend), Node cannot read it directly, frontend needs to read from local storage and hit node.js via API and pass the data.

Comment: You can pass data via API call, you need to create one in node.js, on google you can find 100+ tutorials for same